# Python extract top user name from json

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to get a sorted list or table of users from a loaded dict. I was able to print them as below but I couldn't figure out how to sort them in descending order according to the number of tweets the user name made in the sample. If I'm able to do that I might figure out how to track the to user as well. Thanks!

```
tweets = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=ECHO&rpp=100")
tweets_json = tweets.read() 
data = json.loads(tweets_json)                                                                                                              

for tweet in data['results']:                                                                                           
...    print tweet['from_user_name']                                                                                                                                                               
...    print tweet['to_user_name']                                                                                          
...    print
```

Comment: Without any detail as to what `data` contains, this is unanswerable. Even a link to the API documentation would help here.

Comment: either you can give details of `data` or you can use `print getTopUserNamefromJSON(data)`

Comment: sorry, guess when I copied I missed the first two lines. Added now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tweets = data['results']
tweets.sort(key=lambda tw: tw['from_user_name'], reverse=True)
```

Assuming `tw['from_user_name']` contains number of tweets from given username.

If `tw['from_user_name']` contains username instead then:

```
from collections import Counter

tweets = data['results']
count = Counter(tw['from_user_name'] for tw in tweets)
tweets.sort(key=lambda tw: count[tw['from_user_name']], reverse=True)
```

To print top 10 usernames by number of tweets they send, you don't need to sort tweets:

```
print("\n".join(count.most_common(10)))
```